# Decommissioning Exchange 2013 server - Check if any Emails Flowing Through

Tags: exchange-2013

I am in the process of decommissioning an Exchange 2013 server in favor or a different exchange 2013 server.  The one I am getting rid of is on old hardware are is hardly used and has frequent crashes.

I wanted to find out if there was a way that I could see what mail was still flowing through the old exchange server to avoid possible email loss. I have already moved all mailboxes over to the new exchange server and they are working fine.  The emails that I am most concerned about are `service emails` -- such as emails from printers, servers, applications, etc that I may have missed.

Does anyone know if it is possible to see what mail is flowing through?  All I need is the meta data like sender, receiver, and subject.

Answer (score 1):

What I did when I did the same thing was remove the old server from the send connector and watched the queues on the old server. I could see who and what was still sending to the old server. I would then add the server back in to the send connector to deliver the emails. I did this 3 or 4 times until the queue was always clean. Then removed the old server.

Comment: Thanks, that a great way to do it.  Unfortunately, my server has got so bad the Transport Service will no longer start up to load the Queue.  I suppose I'll have to do the old `Wait until someone complains` technique. I'm pretty sure I've gotten them all though.